# Entity Framework's strange eager loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework 6.1.3. I have an Entity, and it has a reference to another Entity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Users
{
    public System.Guid UserID { get; set; }   
    public System.Guid ExtID { get; set; }       
    public Nullable<System.Guid> UserData_UserDataID { get; set; }   
    public virtual UserData UserData { get; set; }

}
```

I use the following EF query to get all of them:

```
 UserList = new ObservableCollection<Users>((from user in db.Users.Include("UserData") 
                                             where user.ExtID == ExtId1   
                                             orderby user.UserData.Title 
                                             select user).ToList());
```

My grid shows the users correctly when it first loads.

Later, I remove some of the users by using this:

```
      db.Users.Attach(SelectedUser);
      db.Users.Remove(SelectedUser);
      UserList.Remove(SelectedUser);
```

If the user chooses to Cancel the operation, I undo the changes of the context:

```
var changedEntries = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
foreach (var entry in changedEntries.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted))
      {
        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
      }
```

Then I reload the list, using the query above.

Strangely, the new List is not the same as the original: **the removed items' UserData fields are null.**

I use this code to check:

```
UserList.Count(item => item.UserData == null)
```

On the first run, its result is 0. After the remove, the result is equal with the number of the removed items.

Can you tell me why? How could I force them to reload?

Answer (score 2):

> Can you tell me why?

That's because changing entitystate to Unchanged would not reload the dbcontext. you need to manually reload the context something like this:

```
var changedEntries = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
foreach (var entry in changedEntries.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted))
{
    //No need to set entry to Unchanged
    entry.Reload();
}
```

Comment: Interesting. When I set the states to Unchanged, I expect the query to be fully reloaded _from the database_. Is it getting it from cache?

Comment: @Nestor Yes it is from cache (change tracker API) There is two other options 1) you may reinitialize the dbcontext instnace 2) you may include [AsNoTracking()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556203.aspx) to stop ef tracking entities.

Comment: I checked it with Profiler and it gets the data from the database on the second run as well (the SQL query is the same). So the problem is somewhere inside the context.

Comment: @Nestor even if with new query doesn't it reload the data? Try running the same query in ssms.

Comment: The query in SSMS has the correct values. Only the entities in the context don't have the value... Really strange...

Comment: @Nestor Instead of changing state to unchanged call reload on entry object.

Comment: Using Reload helps, but it generates _unnecessary SQL traffic_ as the original query delivers all the necessary data.

Comment: @Nestor Yes I still did not get why second query gets fired and why that did not get dbcontext updated despite of trip to sql server? It is very strange.